# XML Processing System

Tags: web-services, xml, web-server

I need suggestions about any existing robust XML system, either free or paid, that enables automated XML processing. My requirements are like a client application is installed on the client server which fetches incoming XML request documents from a particular location and then sends it to the XML server for processing. The server processes the XML based on the DTD and generates an XML response document ready to be downloaded by the client, which downloads it and stores it in the "Response" folder. Please let me know any suggestions and any alternatives.